# Why MAC address changes after connection?

Tags: debian, mac-address

Recently I noticed that when I connect through wireless, my NIC change MAC address...

Here's my `ip addr` **BEFORE** the connection:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:5b:76:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp4s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether fe:96:23:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Here's my `ip addr` **AFTER** the connection:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether c8:5b:76:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp4s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether f4:8c:50:yy:yy:yy brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.9.100/24 brd 192.168.9.255 scope global dynamic wlp4s0
       valid_lft 86391sec preferred_lft 86391sec
    inet6 fe80::f68c:50ff:feyy:yyyy/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Note that the wireless card change all of its MAC address, not just the last 3 bytes...

I installed `macchanger`, but when prompted I refused to change MAC address for each connection, so I'm sure it is not him!
Also, the MAC address I get when I connect is always the same and the first 3 bytes suggest it is an Intel's NIC which is right.

Is that possible? And how?

Am I missing something?

Comment: fe:96:23 is not a known OUI.

Comment: I just made a copy+paste

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams It doesn't need a known OUI in order to be valid. The first byte `fe` even has the "locally administered" bit set to indicate that it's randomly generated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For privacy reasons, various operating systems have started assigning random MAC addresses to avoid client tracking between networks. Depending on the OS, you might get a random MAC *when connected* (usually stable for a given network), or a random MAC *when scanning* for networks (to disguise the probe requests), or both.

I'm guessing you use NetworkManager. Address randomization when scanning can be disabled via `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`:

```
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
```

Address randomization for *connections* can be disabled using:

```
[connection]
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=permanent
wifi.cloned-mac-address=permanent
```

To adjust *existing* connections:

```
$ nmcli connection modify "My Wi-Fi" wifi.cloned-mac-address permanent
```

It's further described in a developer's [blog post](https://blogs.gnome.org/thaller/2016/08/26/mac-address-spoofing-in-networkmanager-1-4-0/).